# Coloring cells of dataframe based on the condition in R

Tags: r, formattable

I have a dataframe like this example:

```
>df
id  prev_score  cur_score   change
1      10          8         -2
2      8           9          1
3      6           7          1
4      8           8          0
5      8           9          1
```

I would like to color `prev_score` column cells based on the value of `change` column. For example, `if df$change[i] > 0`, `df$prev_score[i]` cell color should be colored dark blue, `if df$change[i] == 0`, `df$prev_score[i]` cell color should be colored blue and `if df$change[i] < 0`, `df$prev_score[i]` cell color should be colored light blue.

Comment: Are you going to plot this dataset ? or are you looking for a colored dataframe such as `formattable` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, tt is not clear if you are looking to change the color of the text or of the cell

For the color of the text, using `formattable`, you can do:

```r
library(formattable)
formattable(df, list(
  prev_score = formatter("span", 
                         style = ~style(font.weight = "bold", color = 
                                          ifelse(change > 0,"darkblue",
                                                 ifelse(change == 0,"blue",
                                                        ifelse(change <0, "lightblue",NA)))))
))
```

[image]

For coloring the box and not the text, you can do the following:

```r
formattable(scores, list(
  prev_score = formatter("span", 
                         style = ~style(display = "block",
                                        font.weight = "bold", 
                                        color = "white",
                                        "border-radius" = "4px",
                                        "padding-right" = "4px",
                                        "background-color" =  
                                          ifelse(change > 0,"darkblue",
                                                 ifelse(change == 0,"blue",
                                                        ifelse(change <0, "lightblue",NA)))))
))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

**Reproducible example**

```r
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                     prev_score = c(10, 8, 6, 8, 8),
                     cur_score = c(8, 9, 7, 8, 9),
                     change = c(-2, 1, 1, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks so much @dc37, it is the solution that I was looking for.

Comment: Hi @dc37, my data and ifelse statement is actually a bit different. Some numbers in my data doesn't fit the ifelse statement, and this returning empty cells in the output. How can I change the code, so I will have numbers instead of empty cells when the data doesn't fit the ifelse statement? Thank you

Comment: I think you just need to change `NA` to `transparent` at the end of the `ifelse`

Comment: Thanks @dc37, I tried `transparent` and `"transparent"`, but none of them worked

Comment: Are you trying to color the cell ? or color the text ?

Comment: I am coloring the cell

Comment: Try to replace `NA` by `black` and see if you can see cells that are not matching conditions

Comment: Ah, it is actually there, it is not visible because it is in white color. I can seen the numbers after changing the cell color into black. Big thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208450/discussion-between-sher-and-dc37).